# Conditionally adding an "NA" row to a list of data frames using a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, addition

I have a list of 52 datasets that are between 5 and 6 rows; they will all need an added column but to add this column the row number needs to be the same. To the sets with 5 rows, I want to add a 6th row with "NA" filling the row as a place holder. Here is where I have started, but I am unsure how to complete the loop because I am unsure what to use for the "df" in the nrow() function. I want this to do nothing to the datasets with 6 rows already.

```
testrows<-if lapply(listallht_allwk, nrow) = 5 { 
    df[nrow(df) + 1 ,] <- NA
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Data

Here I've created two dummy data frames for demonstration.

```
df <- data.frame(row = 1:5, col1 = LETTERS[1:5])
df2 <- data.frame(row = 1:6, col1 = LETTERS[1:6])

df_list <- list(df, df2)

df_list
[[1]]
  row col1
1   1    A
2   2    B
3   3    C
4   4    D
5   5    E

[[2]]
  row col1
1   1    A
2   2    B
3   3    C
4   4    D
5   5    E
6   6    F
```

#### Code

It might be better to use `if else` inside `lapply`. Simply `rbind` the dataframe with `NA` to get an extra row of `NA`.

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  if (nrow(x) == 5) {
    rbind(x, NA)
  } else {
    x
  }
})

[[1]]
  row col1
1   1    A
2   2    B
3   3    C
4   4    D
5   5    E
6  NA <NA>

[[2]]
  row col1
1   1    A
2   2    B
3   3    C
4   4    D
5   5    E
6   6    F
```

Comment: Thank you--that worked wonderfully! So, when it modifies the list, it creates all new data sets instead of modifying the original dataframes in the list---is there a way to modify the original data frame so that I do not need to index the dataframe from the list and re-store the dataframe? I have had this issue before and haven't had luck figuring it out. @benson23

Comment: @LexiHeger If your list contains named data frames, you can do `lapply(...) %>% list2env(.GlobalEnv)`, this will create data frames in your global environment where the variable names would be the names in your list